# What is the best way to "combine" two Fortran subroutines with very similar functionalities but slight differences?

Tags: inheritance, fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I have two modules with an init subroutine that look as following:

```
module letter_A
contains  
subroutine a_init()
  *do something*
  call my_function(1)
  print *, "letter A init"
end module letter_A

module letter_B
contains  
subroutine b_init()
  *do something*
  call my_function(2)
  print *, "letter B init"
end module letter_B
```

I would like to create a supermodule and convert the modules `A` and `B` to submodules, and outsource as much functionality as possible to the supermodule to reduce the amount of redundant code in my application. Currently, the only way I can think of how to do this is as following:

```
module letter
contains  
subroutine letter_init()
  *do something*
#if defined(A)
  a_init(1)
#elif defined(B)
  b_init(2)
#endif
end module letter

submodule(letter) A
contains  
subroutine a_init()
  call my_function(1)
  print *, "letter A init"
end module letter_A

...
```

However, this only works for this particular minimal example. If I have more function calls with more identical `*do something*` blocks inbetween, it becomes harder to separate the redundant parts in a seperate module and it's also not very nice to have to pass 10+ values to an init function. Is there a more sophisticated way of solving this problem?

Comment: Submodules are a feature of Fortran 2008. Do you really mean these submodules or ordinary modules? Given your use of the version tags (please choose only one) I suppose you mean ordinary modules.

Comment: The question title is at odds with the question text.  I read the title and expected to find a question about two very similar subroutines but found that it is all about submodules.  If you find that you have identical `*do something*` blocks in multiple locations, don't you just turn that into a subroutine called `do_something` and call it from multiple locations?

Comment: ... and the use of pseudocode such as `#if defined(A)` makes me wonder if OP is looking for optional arguments?

Comment: Or possibly pacing a procedure as an argument. Or just splitting off "do something" into its own subroutine

Comment: Inheritance/polymorphism with an abstract base class?

Comment: Why are you using preprocessor directives?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something important (?), but the answer to your question looks as simple as that to me:

```
subroutine letter_init(letter)
  character(1), intent(in) :: letter
  !*do something*
  if (letter == 'A') then
     call my_function(1)
  else if (letter == 'B') then
     call my_function(2)
  end if
  print *, "letter "//letter//" init"
end subroutine letter_init
```

Comment: I think this is a good guess at answering a rather obscure question.